# is there any way to add the description present in name link using css selector

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

**here is my new code in this code I got the output like this**

{   "names": "Augustine T.K. James (6360)",     "dates": "29/11/2021" } {   "description": "Augustine T.K. James (6360) as the sole proprietor of Messrs. James & Co (“the Firm”) had been punished and imposed a suspension of 3 months effective 1/1/2022, fine of RM5000-00, costs of RM4000-00 and ordered to attend a course conducted by the Institute on Audit Quality Enhancement Program by the Disciplinary Committee of the Institute on 29/11/2021 after the Firm had been rated as ‘unsatisfactory’ as indicated in the Monitoring Review Report dated 10/6/2019 which detailed the weaknesses in the audit work performed." }

I want them to be under one curly braces like
{
"name": "XYZ",
"date":"29/11/2021"
"description:":"XYZ xyz xyz"
}

```
package com.company;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.juneau.serializer.SerializeException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.apache.juneau.json.JsonSerializer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SerializeException {

        ArrayList<Product> name_date_list = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Desc_Product> desc_list = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> combine_list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\browser driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
        driver1.get("https://www.mia.org.my/v2/surveillance/disciplinary/decisions.aspx");


        for(int i = 0 ;i<8;i++){
            for (int j =0;j<10;j++ ){
                try {
                    List<WebElement> d1 = driver1.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[id*='PageContents_LVDecisions_ctrl']"));
                    WebElement webElementd1 = d1.get(j);
                    webElementd1.click();

                    List<WebElement> d3 = driver1.findElements(By.cssSelector("article.br5.bgaliceblue.alignjustify"));
                    WebElement webElementd3 = d3.get(0);

                    JsonSerializer descSerialization = JsonSerializer.DEFAULT_READABLE;
                    Desc_Product desc_product = new Desc_Product(webElementd3.getText());
                    String desc_json =  descSerialization.serialize(desc_product);
                    desc_list.add(desc_product);
                    //System.out.println(desc_json);
                    
                    driver1.navigate().back();
                    
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                }
            }
            //System.out.println("pressed next page");
            List<WebElement> ed1 = driver1.findElements(By.cssSelector("input.dbutton"));
            WebElement webElemented1 = ed1.get(4);
            webElemented1.click();
        }
        WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
        driver2.get("https://www.mia.org.my/v2/surveillance/disciplinary/decisions.aspx");
        for (int i =0 ;i<8;i++){
            List<WebElement> e1 = driver2.findElements(By.cssSelector("td.widthtd75"));
            List<WebElement> e3 = driver2.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[id*='PageContents_LVDecisions_ctrl']"));
            for(int j = 0 ;j<10;j++){
                try {
                    
                    WebElement webElement1 = e1.get(j);
//                    System.out.println(webElement1.getText());
                    WebElement webElement3 = e3.get(j);
//                    System.out.println(webElement3.getText());
                    
                    JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.DEFAULT_READABLE;

                    Product product = new Product(webElement1.getText(),webElement3.getText());
                    
                    try {
                        String name_date =  jsonSerializer.serialize(product);
                        name_date_list.add(product);
                   }
                    catch (SerializeException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                }catch (Exception e){}
            }
            List<WebElement> e2 = driver2.findElements(By.cssSelector("input.dbutton"));
            WebElement webElement = e2.get(4);
            webElement.click();
        }

        for(int i =0; i<100;i++){

            JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.DEFAULT_READABLE;

            String name_date =  jsonSerializer.serialize(name_date_list.get(i));
            System.out.println(name_date);

            String desc_ = jsonSerializer.serialize((desc_list.get(i)));
            System.out.println(desc_);

            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
        }
        
    }


}
```

**Description class**
package com.company;

```
import org.apache.juneau.annotation.BeanConstructor;

public class Desc_Product {

    private String description;

    @BeanConstructor(properties = "description")
    public Desc_Product(String description) {

        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

//    @Override
//    public String toString() {
//        return "Desc_Product{" +
//                "description='" + description + '\'' +
//                '}';
//    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " \n" +
                "description :"+ description;
    }
}
```

**product class**

```
package com.company;

import org.apache.juneau.annotation.BeanConstructor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Product {

    private String names;
    private String dates;
    private String description;

    public Product() {
    }

    public String getNames() {
        return String.valueOf(names);
    }

    public void setNames(String names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    public String getDates() {
        return dates;
    }

    public void setDates(String dates) {
        this.dates = dates;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

//
//    @BeanConstructor(properties = "names,dates,description")
//    public Product(String names, String dates, String description) {
//        this.names = names;
//        this.dates = dates;
//        this.description = description;
//    }
    @BeanConstructor(properties = "names,dates")
    public Product(String names, String dates) {
        this.names = names;
        this.dates = dates;
    }

//    @BeanConstructor(properties = "names,dates,description")
//    public Product(String names, String dates,String description) {
//        this.names = names;
//        this.dates = dates;
//        this.description = description;
//    }

//    @Override
//    public String toString() {
//        return "{" +
//                "names='" + names + '\'' +
//                ", dates='" + dates + '\'' +
//                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
//                '}';
//    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "name :"+names +"\n"+
                "dates :"+dates;
    }
}
```

Comment: link :- https://www.mia.org.my/v2/surveillance/disciplinary/decisions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the Desc_Product or Product classes. I tried to recreate your program anyways. When trying to recreate it, I managed to print out the description on each page. [Here is my recreation](https://mx1.maxtaf.com/cases/c1a96b2a-f93b-4444-9317-0e05ef055a2c?projectId=bugtestproject2).

Is there a reason you need to use the serializer or do you only need to scrape the pages for their description? If You only need the description then check the example I linked and let me know what you think. (I would have commented all this but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet)

Comment: Hi MDelic, 

Thanks so much for your time I did some more research and got some work around I fetch name and date together and description separately but now the problem is I want  them in a single file I ll share the code please suggest me any changes

Comment: have you tried making description an attribute of Product and retrieving the value from a Desc_Product class? I'm no expert in Java's JsonSerializer class but looking at your code that would be my go to. You could feed a Desc_Product object to the constructor of Product for example.