# Merge two jsonSerializer into a single jsonSerializer output should be in json format

Tags: java, json, selenium, web-scraping

```
for(int i =0; i<100;i++){

            JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.DEFAULT_READABLE;

            String name_date =  jsonSerializer.serialize(name_date_list.get(i));
            System.out.println(name_date);

            String desc_ = jsonSerializer.serialize((desc_list.get(i)));
            System.out.println(desc_);

            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
        }
```

My output is like this

{
"names": "Augustine T.K. James (6360)",
"dates": "29/11/2021"
}
{
"description": "Augustine T.K. James (6360) as the sole proprietor of Messrs. James & Co (“the Firm”) had been punished and imposed a suspension of 3 months effective 1/1/2022, fine of RM5000-00, "
}

I want output like this
{
"name":"Augustine T.K. James (6360)",
"dates": "29/11/2021",
"description": "Augustine T.K. James (6360) as the sole proprietor of Messrs. James & Co (“the Firm”) had been punished and imposed a suspension of 3 months effective 1/1/2022, fine of RM5000-00, "

}

Comment: It's very hard to help without any idea what the types involved are. (I'd also strongly recommend following Java naming conventions, certainly for sample code on Stack Overflow.) If you could provide a [mcve] it will be easier to help you.

Comment: ok let me add my some more code

Comment: here is my full program :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71248892/is-there-any-way-to-add-the-description-present-in-name-link-using-css-selector/71251666#71251666

Comment: That's code someone else has provided in an answer, with a link that doesn't even appear to work at the moment. Instead of that, please provide a [mcve] *in this question*.